# $\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} \leq \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^{n}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit disk in the complex plane and let $f$ be an holomorphic function on $D$ such that $$|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{1 - |z|}, \,\,\, \forall z \in D$$ Show that $$\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} \leq \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^{n}}$$**What I've done**:

I've used the Cauchy Inequalities $$\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} \leq r^{-n} \sup\{|f(\zeta)| : |\zeta| = r \}, \text{where } \{z: |z| = r\} \subseteq D$$ To show that $$\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{r^{n}{1-r}}$$Now, it seems to me that the only thing missing is to find some appropriate $r$. However, I am not managing to do it. Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: You need absolute values in the second inequality (and the title) and a bunch of other places

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You'll get the best inequality by maximizing $r^n(1-r).$